# How to debug why application is restarting

Tags: android

I don't mind letting the application get killed by the Android OS, I'm trying to debug why the application is restarting after being killed by low memory situations. I'm using

`adb shell dumpsys activity processes`

To read the "Process LRU list (sorted by oom_adj):"

My current problem is when I do the following steps and read the dumpsys after each step.

- App Running

`Proc #)13: adj=fore /FA trm= 0 6124:com.thisoldthing (top-activity)`

- App closed by back button

`Proc #20: adj=bak  /B  trm= 0 6124:com.thisoldthing (started-bg-ui-services)`

- Killed after running stressrobo

`Proc #13: adj=svc  /B  trm=15 8488:com.thisoldthing (started-services)`

Now the application is not killed when putting the device into a low memory situation. More worrisome is I want to know why it restarted.

Comment: Without knowing much about the app it's tough to say, but it appears that it is providing some sort of service to the system separate from the GUI.  What type of app is it?

Comment: [How](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) did you start your service?

Comment: It's bound in Application.onCreate `bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

Comment: I'm working with 4.0+ I don't call startService. The service is created by the `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` flag and does not pass through onStartCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android will try to keep your service alive as long as possible. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) of Context.startService() says: "If any errors happen in the service's process, it will automatically be restarted." My understanding and experience let me believe that it will happen regardless you started with startService() or bindService(), but the last one has no mention to that though.

So, if you don't want get your service restarted, you need to close bound connections before kill it. Unfortunately the application can not rely in onDestroy() being called in killing conditions so any unbindService() calls will depend on application's life-cycle. You will need to handle it by yourself.

Finally, bind connections was not designed to remain forever. They should connect, do the job and unbind. Keeping this in mind, android does the right think restarting services with bound connections.